# How to reorder the table serial no after deleting the row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table with few buttons in each row. I have to remove the table row when I click the delete button of each row. My problem here is when I delete the row the S.N. is not arranged in order. For Example: if there are 5 rows and once I remove the first row, it will order as 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S.N.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Modified Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php 
    $sn = 1;
    while($result= mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {

        ?>
        <tr id=<?= $result[0];?>>
            <td><? echo $sn++; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $result[1] ?></td>
            <td><? echo $result[2] ?></td>
            <td><? echo $result[3] ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="delete">Delete</a>
                <a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('#delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: don't use same id in DOM

Comment: assign a class to **S.N.** column `<td class="sn">`. and iterate over these `<td>`s to update the content.

Comment: I didnot get properly. can you plz help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not have same ID. IDs must be unique. you can rather use class and then class selector to target those elements:

```
$('.delete').on('click......
```

For reordering, you can use index of element in `.attr` callback function to set id based on index:

```
$('table tbody tr').attr('id',function(i,o){
  return i++ ;
});
```

Comment: Have you added above code in click handler for delete.